# Chart kick Timeline using Ruby on Rails and dynamic data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic, chartkick

I've installed Chartkick within my ROR app and I'm looking to use the timeline feature to display projects to give a simple and quick overview.

```
<%= @projects.each do |project|
  timeline [ 
  ['project.hospital', "project.construction_start", "project.construction_end"],
  ] %>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to get it to display all projects with the construction_start and end format be set at YYYY-MM-DD

I have no idea what to do... anything assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is showing something you dont want, the loop instead the timeline, and it's showing , not one timeline but many of them .
Change your code to:

```
<% data = @projects.pluck(:hospital,:construction_start,:construction_end) %>
<%= timeline  data  %>
```

This should only create one timeline with all the data about the hospitals of all projects you passed from the controller .

Note that this will only work on Rails 4+. If you have Rails 3 you will have to override the pluck method (it's not hard actually)

Comment: Thanks Ruben, however this will create multiple timelines... I'm looking to group the projects within the a single timeline.

Comment: Oh, ok give me a moment then.

Comment: Thanks Ruben, if you have a look at http://chartkick.com scroll down to timeline you will see 3 items within a single timeline. I'm trying to achieve the same thing... only please note the format.

Comment: `<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <%= timeline [
                ['project.hospital',
                 'project.construction_start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")',
                 'project.construction_end.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")'],
               ] %>
<% end %>`  

Will the above work with regards to changing the date to YYYY-mm-dd

Comment: Try now, it should create one timeline

Comment: Hi Ruben, I'm getting the following error now? undefined method `strftime' for :construction_start:Symbol

Comment: Try it without strftime, it seems that rails don't recognize the attribute as date but as a symbol, which is odd.
Post your Model code and the Controller too (Only the action where you are "building" @projects)

Comment: Sport on, I removed the .srtftime and had to remove the [ ] from data as it was adding an extra one! it's all fixed! thanks heaps!

Comment: True, my fault , pluck actually map the values into an array (if it's one value) or an array of arrays (if it's more than one). Im glad that it works and good luck with Ruby , it's really fun as language.